# Unable to publish JWT config file in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I am using **laravel 5.7** and i install fresh **laravel project** and setup **JWT service** providers in **app.php**. Now i run command for publish **JWT** config file but i got error like this

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Tymon\JWT\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found

I don't get to how to fix this.

Comment: did you run `composer require tymon/jwt-auth`?

Comment: i run `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:0.5.*-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install via composer

Run the following command to pull in the latest version:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

Add service provider

Add the service provider to the `providers` array in the `config/app.php` config file as follows:

```
'providers' => [

    ...

    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Comment: okay but where i run this command means i run this command on my existing project or new project?

Comment: @Beerussama you can run this command via the command prompt, yes you can be used in an existing  project also

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link: [laravel-jwt-api](https://github.com/Boni619/laravel-jwt-api)

Step 1: `composer update`

Step 2: `php artisan migrate`

Step 3: `php artisan serve`

and put post in postman

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login

i hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
>
> php artisan config:cache
>
> php artisan vendor:publish  and then select
>
> Which provider or tag's files would you like to publish`enter code here`
>   [0 ] Publish files from all providers and tags listed below
>   [1 ] Provider: Facade\
> ```
>
> > Blockquote
>
> Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider
>         [2 ] Provider: Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider
>         [3 ] Provider: Fruitcake\Cors\CorsServiceProvider
>         [4 ] Provider: Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider
>         [5 ] Provider: Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider
>         [6 ] Provider: Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider
>         [7 ] Provider: Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider
>         [8 ] Provider: Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider
>         [9 ] Provider: Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider
>         [10] Tag: config
>         [11] Tag: cors
>         [12] Tag: flare-config
>         [13] Tag: ignition-config
>         [14] Tag: laravel-errors
>         [15] Tag: laravel-mail
>         [16] Tag: laravel-notifications
>         [17] Tag: laravel-pagination
>
> > 9
>
> ```
> Copied File [/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/config/config.php] To [/config/jwt.php]
> Publishing complete.
> ```